# SIGABRT Error swift

Tags: swift, runtime-error, sigabrt

Could anyone help me understand why Im getting this error? It seems to be happening when I load one of my view controllers but I can't see why.

What usually causes an error like this?

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextInputTraits length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbf924828a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010664ac65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105f27bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001066520ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065a813c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065a7cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x0000000107ddf728 _TTSf4g_d___TFSSCfMSSFT12_cocoaStringPSs9AnyObject__SS + 120
    6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x0000000107dc01a3 _TFSSCfMSSFT12_cocoaStringPSs9AnyObject__SS + 19
    7   Project1                            0x00000001054ec3bd _TToFC8ASA_Rank22SettingsViewControllers9ASANumberSS + 61
    8   Foundation                          0x0000000105abdb53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106592d50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106d1b4eb -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106b736d8 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106b73cc8 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106b73f39 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000106b743ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010710132d -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 65
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000106b4ed69 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 105
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000106b80248 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1761
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106b826c1 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106b825e5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106a44d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106b5650a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000106b558d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000106a91958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000106a92282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000106a58541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000106a65cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000106a4059c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010657e431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065742fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106573934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106573366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a1e0a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000106a438c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    34  Project1                            0x00000001054f70c7 main + 135
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108530145 start + 1
    36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please ask for any other informations that is helpful

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3):

You most likely have an Outlet assigned to an element on the view controller you are transitioning to that is no longer connected to your code. This [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StNo1ZBmxww) video explains it in more detail.

To hunt down this issue, try right-clicking on all your elements (UILabels, UIViews, UIButton...) with the assistant editor open and cross check to see if the outlet name is referenced in the view controller.

[image: Example]